# What is a person called who is writing exams in the name of another person?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a person who is writing exams in place of/in the name of other persons?

Comment: I'd call them a cheater.

Comment: I would like more information. Do you mean someone who was legally commissioned to write in someone else's name? It's not exam-specific, but the word I would recommend is [*ghostwriter*](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=ghostwriter&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=ghostwriter+meaning&safe=active), which Google says means "a person whose job it is to write material for someone else who is the named author."

Comment: @dingo_dan I'm pretty certain they mean cheating on exams.  They're using writing exams in the way we say taking exams.  Outside AmE this is the normal way to express this.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Comment: @tchrist Assuming British English, this question is completely clear and asks for a term for a specific, important form of academic dishonesty, not an esoteric rude word.

Answer (score 1):

It is called [Impersonation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_dishonesty) and the person perpetrating it is an *impostor* as mentioned elsewhere

> Impersonation is a form of cheating whereby a different person than the student assigned an assignment or exam completes it.

Comment: When done fraudulently, such as at an exam, or voting, it is often, in the UK, described as 'personation'. There is indeed an electoral crime of 'personation'.  'Impersonation', is more the theatre usage.

Comment: We don't use the word 'personation' in the U.S. The same word is used for both fraudulent and innocuous 'impersonation'.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the concept of a [Ringer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ringer) has been used in this context.

Comment: That is a slang expression.

Comment: @mplungjan Why would that discredit it?  It's a fairly common bit of slang.

Comment: OP did not ask for slang. Most word requests here are not for slang words.

Comment: @mplungjan I think you'll find that the line between slang and acceptable usage is very vague, and depends a lot on context. The fact that [other dictionaries](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ringer#Etymology_3) don't mark it as slang is a good indication of that.

Comment: @mplungjan The OP doesn't offer a context, so the formality of language required can't be assumed.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan the other dictionary you mention does not give ringer as someone who cheats, but as someone resembling someone, the much more used "dead ringer" I have never heard the word ringer used for an academic impostor. I can see a dead ringer being necessary if a picture ID is required to take the exam, but not otherwise

Comment: @mplungjan While I agree that most word requests are not for slang, it should be up to the OP to decide whether it fits their needs or not.  That's what the up vote and accept system are for.

Comment: Sure, but just mention it. In any case I disagree it is a widely used word, that should perhaps also be mentioned

Comment: I have definitely heard the word _ringer_ used in an academic context to mean someone playing this particular role in this particular form of cheating. In writing, it often appears in quotation marks. Examples are [here](http://www.depts.ttu.edu/studentconduct/Academic%20Integrity%20Documents/Preventing%20Academic%20Dishonesty.pdf) and [here](http://blogs.ajc.com/get-schooled-blog/2012/11/25/a-new-cheating-scandal-aspiring-teachers-hiring-ringers/). Googling reveals plenty more.

Comment: @BenKovitz I stand corrected. Although the link is from Texas - so they are likely fixin' to make the ringer fess up before he skedaddles.

Answer (score 1):

I once knew an English language examiner who had to sit and write an English exam paper for a candidate. The exam candidate would dictate his answers to the ***scribe***, and because the scribe was an examiner, she knew when to ask the candidate to spell out words learners typically had difficulty with. The candidate in question had severe dyslexia and difficulty in holding a pen. Obviously the candidate was in a separate room, and extra time was awarded to complete the writing paper.
The Cambridge English Language Assessment exam board calls this *helper*/*aide*/*scribe*, **[a reader](http://www.cambridgeenglish.org/exams-and-qualifications/special-circumstances/)**.

> 8) **Having someone read to you or write down your answers**
>
> **A reader** is a person who will read the questions out to you. Note that
>   the reader will not explain the questions to you and cannot give you
>   any advice. They can also read back your answers to you. In Reading
>   papers, a reader is not normally allowed to read out texts to you and
>   you are not normally allowed to use screen-reading software to do
>   this.
>
> If you want someone to write down your answers, you should note that:
>
> - you will be asked to spell certain words
> - you must also give the punctuation.

Comment: Since the question was not that clear (to me anyway), I think this is a possible answer, and it's certainly interesting and useful information.

Comment: @rabbit Thank you for telling me the post was useful. It may not be the answer the OP was looking for, we'll never know, but I'm glad someone found it informative.

Answer (score 0):

That person is an [**impostor**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impostor).  They are pretending to be someone else for the purpose of deceit.

The act of taking someone else's exam is cheating.  [There were numerous scandals of this type a few years ago.](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/12/02/education/on-long-island-sat-cheating-was-hardly-a-secret.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question more specifically, I would have to say the only word you can use is "assistant."  You specifically asked about writing tests/exams, not the person answering or taking it.

Often in contemporary American universities, that person is a Teachers Assistant.

Comment: Writing exams in other dialects (BrE, CanE, AuE, InE) means the same as taking exams in AmE.  So, your answer is not correct here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this person is often referred to as a **stand-in**.

> a person who stands in for another, esp. in a performance; a
>   substitute.

I have also heard of **proxy** being used and online services refer to them as **tutors** or **experts**.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's called a "proxy", as in a substitute.